# Facebook graph API is not returning single event even when user access token of event admin is provided

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently developing a Facebook app that uses the graph api to get user events so I am more than aware of the current situation regarding the Facebook API I currently can not retrieve single facebook events, for an open public event even when the user token of the event admin is provided. I notice when I use the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) it's also not working.

EG graph.facebook.com/v2.12/442114182884350?access_token=[USER ACCESS TOKEN OF EVENT ADMIN]

Does anyone know what's going on? Is Facebook just going to shut down the whole API?

Comment: Pretty sure your app needs to get approved first. And App Review is currently paused

Comment: paused ? Do we know how long for? My events website is falling apart!

Comment: Actually that doesn't quite make sense becuase when I use Object Explorer and request a user token that isn't associated with any app and I still cant retrieve an event listing.

Comment: A user access token is always associated with an app.

Comment: When you select "get user access token" on [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) what app is it associating with ? Also thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It is associated with the selected app.

Comment: Right so if you dont select an app it's just the Facebook API app ? Right so the app and user have to be admin of the event have to use the API. It's weird I can't use the object explorer to see my own stuff that I created right now.

Comment: As I said in my first comment. Pretty sure the app needs to be approved.

Comment: Sidan you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process
>   should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and
>   Groups APIs will lose access today.

Information Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/